# ASP.NET Boilerplate IRepository extension method

Tags: c#, repository, extension-methods, asp.net-boilerplate, irepository

For [Organization Units](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Organization-Units), we used the code below to **get entities in an Organization Unit including its child Organization Units**. Is it reasonable and how to extend the `IRepository` to add this feature to all entities?

```
public virtual List<Product> GetProductsInOuIncludingChildren(long organizationUnitId)
{
    var code = _organizationUnitRepository.Get(organizationUnitId).Code;

    var query =
        from product in _productRepository.GetAll()
        join organizationUnit in _organizationUnitRepository.GetAll() on product.OrganizationUnitId equals organizationUnit.Id
        where organizationUnit.Code.StartsWith(code)
        select product;

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, inherit `IMustHaveOrganizationUnit`:

```cs
public class Product : Entity, IMustHaveOrganizationUnit
{
    public long OrganizationUnitId { get; set; }
}
```

Then define the extension method:

```cs
public static class RepositoryExtensions
{
    public static List<TEntity> GetAllInOuIncludingChildren<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>(
        this IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> repository,
        long organizationUnitId
    )
        where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>, IMustHaveOrganizationUnit
    {
        using (var organizationUnitRepository = repository.GetIocResolver().ResolveAsDisposable<IRepository<OrganizationUnit, long>>())
        {
            var code = organizationUnitRepository.Object.Get(organizationUnitId).Code;

            var query =
                from entity in repository.GetAll()
                join organizationUnit in organizationUnitRepository.Object.GetAll() on entity.OrganizationUnitId equals organizationUnit.Id
                where organizationUnit.Code.StartsWith(code)
                select entity;

            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var products = _productRepository.GetAllInOuIncludingChildren(organizationUnitId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code.

**Interface:**

```
public interface ITestRepository : IRepository<Test, int>
{

}
```

**Class:**

```
public class TestRepository : YourProjectNameRepositoryBase<Test, int>, ITestRepository
{
    public TestRepository(IDbContextProvider<YourProjectNameDbContext> dbContextProvider, IObjectMapper objectMapper)
        : base(dbContextProvider, objectMapper)
        {
        }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public class TestAppService : YouProjectNameAppServiceBase, ITestAppService
{
    private readonly ITestRepository _testRepository;
    public TestAppService(ITestRepository testRepository,
    
}
```

**Update**

In the latest version, there's no need to pass `objectmapper` and you need to use the updated constructor below:

```
public class TestRepository : YourProjectNameRepositoryBase<Test, int>, ITestRepository
{
    public TestRepository(IDbContextProvider<YourProjectNameDbContext> dbContextProvider)
        : base(dbContextProvider)
        {
        }
}
```